# Google Sheets Sparklines - colour each bar in a barchart

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sparklines

I have a collection of sparklines that looks like this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

Now, everyday of the week is assigned a colour.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Feel free to edit my spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zzDY-K6yALg2iXleRPBJaVdlXucmH7ryOgAPqIvzff0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

**EDIT (2018/08/22 18:06 GMT):**

Or is this perhaps possible to do in Microsoft Excel 2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

According to the [reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en), the 2 color positions you may set is last and first columns:

`=SPARKLINE(data,{"charttype","column"; "firstcolor", "red"; "lastcolor", "green"; "ymin", 0})`

[image]

Making more columns with different colors is impossible according to the current formula settings, you may refer to the Google team to make what you want:

menu `Help` > `Report a problem` and write what you want to get.

## Workaround

The way to make a similar-looking result is to create 7 separate charts:

[image]

The formula for H1 (copy down and right) is:

`=SPARKLINE(A2,{"charttype","column"; "firstcolor", H$1; "ymin", yMin; "ymax", yMax})`

where

yMin is:

`=MIN(dataRange)`

yMax is:

`=MAX(dataRange)`

`dataRange` is range `A2:G8` for my sample.

---

Used [Color Pallets](http://www.color-hex.com/color-palettes/) for finding colors.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, which is cool but I want every bar to have a different colour...

Comment: @semiflex, I found the workaround, please see the edit.